# How to develop a client web application that execute Rest Ws Spring

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-mvc

In my application server Wildfly I have a war which contains code of a RESTful Web Service done with Apache CXF and Spring Framework, this war call an external ws.
With Postman I call API inside my war with success :-) , I ask what technology is better to develope my new client web application to emulate Postman.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I always use the Apache HTTP client to call external web services, regardless if it is SOAP or REST using JSON or XML or whatever other data format.

The reason is: In real live, more than 50% of all web services do not follow the standards. Working around the standards is often hard work when you use frameworks. But with the Apache HTTP client it is easy to implement workarounds for whatever might happen, for example:

- Fix wrong XML Namespaces or content by search/replace before parsing it.
- Process HTTP result codes in non-standard way
- Send and receive custom HTTP headers
- Use requests that combine GET (Url-) parameters with POST body
- non-standard encryption
- non-standard authentication (not everything that they call OAuth2 is really OAuth2)
- Work with certificates - even self-made certifictes that do not match any root certificate

All that might sound ridiculous to you but it happens very very often in the projects where I was involved in. The Apache HTTP client gives you full access to the HTTP protocol and is easy to understand.

You can still marshal and unmarshal the objects to XML/JSON using your framework. But it is better to keep control over the many small details of the HTTP communication.

Comment: Thanks, I have file wsdl, I follow step on https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf, and If I try with Axis the web app generated miss some methods, if i choose Apache CXF wizard produces only java classed without jsp pages, if I choose Axis2 wizard failed

Comment: As I wrote, forget these wizards. You can try to fix the wsdl but sooner or later you have other problems with them and then you spend again more time in finding a workaround than writing these few lines of code yourself.

Comment: Solved, I'm creating a new web app with struts2 , without using any wizard of Eclipse. My jsp of web app invoke with Rest my ws war (done with Apache cxf and Spring). This war invokes with soap the external ws (done with axis). Handwriting is the only solution. Thanks Stefan :-)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Spring RestTemplate. You can inject the RestTemplate in your beans and send GET and POST easily:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

public class Test {

   @Autowired
   RestTemplate restTemplate;

   public ResponseEntity<Response> test(String url, Request request){
        return restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, Response.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: please explain to the user to how to add the rest template in your answer.

Comment: Hi. Yes with struts2 I am using restTemplate to invoke my ws. My target was to have a web frontend auto generated from a ws as you can do with axis and Eclispe. Now i'm writing a web app by zero with Struts2. I solved as has written Stefan, forgot wizards